# Ninject WCF Garbage Collection on repositories

Tags: c#, wcf, garbage-collection, ninject

I'm using Ninject 2.2 with the WCF extension.  On most of my services the repositories are instantiated/released quickly.  However, one of my services performs long-running operations (2-3 min).  If I watch the w3wp process I can see the TCP/IP connections being established with SQL and I can run sp_who2 on SQL and see the connections.

When these operations are complete, the connections remain open for 5-10 minutes.

I don't see new connections being spawned when I run the operation multiple times but I will have multiple instances of the app running and I saw a performance degradation previously while spamming those long running operations and it fixed itself after several minutes.

**Could this garbage collection be part of the problem and how can it be addressed?**

Here is my Ninject binding:

```
Bind<ISomeRepository>().To<SomeRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

Here is my WCF binding:

```
<binding name="xxx" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
  openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
  bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" 
  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
  maxReceivedMessageSize="99999999" messageEncoding="Text"
  textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="false" allowCookies="false">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="90" maxStringContentLength="99999" 
    maxArrayLength="99999999" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
    enabled="true" />
  <security mode="..."/>
</binding>

<service name="SomeService" 
  behaviorConfiguration="abcd">
  <endpoint name="BasicEndPoint" address="http://localhost/SomeService.svc" 
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="xxx"
    contract="ISomeJobService"/>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```

I realize one option is to reduce the number of repositories in use by the service down to one but I'm really looking for an interim solution.

Comment: Look for recent posts in the ninject tag around this - The WCF extensions dont deterministically Dispose per-request stuff as the ASP.NET pipeline integration does but there's stuff in 2.3 which should make it out into 2.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`InRequestScope` has no function in WCF *unless* you are hosting in [IIS compatibility mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx).  That is not the default mode, nor is it recommended for most purposes.

What will actually happen when you try this is that Ninject will use a `null` scope, which is equivalent to not specifying any scope at all. That in turn results in the standard [cache and collect](http://web.archive.org/web/20090525055258/http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/) behaviour, which means Ninject will dispose of those connections (thus releasing them back into the connection pool) whenever it feels like it, to state it in very simplistic terms.

The closest analog to this in WCF is the `OperationScope`. You can bind using

```
Bind(...).To(...).InScope(() => OperationContext.Current)
```

This used to be a half-baked solution but I think it should work properly now, because the `NinjectServiceHostFactory` adds a service behaviour which automatically notifies the cache when the "request" (that is, the operation) is over.

This support was added to the official extension very recently, I think as recently as March '11, so make sure you're using the latest.  At the time of writing, that's 2.3.0.0.

Comment: Thank you for the information - if I could up vote multiple times I would.  Did you just learn this from the source code or is there an article on this topic somewhere?

Comment: @Mayo: I wrote my own OperationScope extension a long time ago and decided to check the Ninject.Extensions.Wcf source before posting it, which was where I got the info that it's now (apparently) supported in the main library. Documentation on the Ninject extensions is, sadly, pretty scant.

Comment: Is this still the 'done thing' for the lifetime of an object (e.g. repo) within a WCF call?

Comment: @Mike: The `InRequestScope` extension is now a plugin-based method in `Ninject.Web.Common`, so it should work in IIS-hosted WCF services. If you're self-hosting, I'm not entirely sure; try it and see.