# When does WCF service host destroy custom IDispatchMessageInspector?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a custom implementation of the IDispatchMessageInspector interface, and my code is working 99% fine.

My problem is that I need to free some managed objects when the WCF service host is killed and/or frees an instance of my class. My objects to free implement IDisposable but they aren't being disposed.  I've been through the MSDN library (more confused) and the SO archives, but haven't found anything that addresses the question "When/where does a WCF service host destroy MessageInspectors?"

Do I need to hook an event someplace?  Do I need to implement something even more arcane from the ServiceModel namespace?

Can anyone give me a pointer in the right direction?

**Edit 1: Clarifications**

At the moment, I am running in the IDE using the automatic webserver. I am not ultimately in control of the host once in production, could be any of the valid server host choices.

The MyCore.My and MyCore.MyProperties objects are the ones I am trying to dispose of when the WCF server host is killed/bounced.

Even when I have killed the webserver processes (those things in the Taskbar) the Dispose() is never called.

**Edit 2: Code snippets added.**

```
using /* snip */
using MyCore = Acme.My;

namespace My.SOAP
{
    public class MyMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        protected static MyCore.My _My;
        protected static MyCore.MyProperties _MyProps;
        protected static ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyCore.AnotherSecretThing> _anotherSecretThings = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyCore.AnotherSecretThing>();

        protected static void InitMy()
        {
            if (_My != null) return;

            _MyProps = new MyCore.MyProperties();
            MyCore.MySqlDatabaseLogger logger = new MyCore.MySqlDatabaseLogger(_MyProps);
            _My = new MyCore.My(logger);
        }

        public MyMessageInspector()
        {
            InitMy();
        }

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,    System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            MyMessageHeader header = null;
            try
            {
                // find My header
                Int32 headerPosition = request.Headers.FindHeader(MyMessageHeaderKey.MyHeaderElementName, MyMessageHeaderKey.MyNamespace);
                // get reader
                XmlDictionaryReader reader = request.Headers.GetReaderAtHeader(headerPosition);
                // get My header object
                header = MyMessageHeader.ReadHeader(reader);
                // add to incoming messages properties dictionary
                OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.Add(MyMessageHeaderKey.MyHeaderElementName, header);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // log via ExceptionHandlingBlock
            }

            MyCore.SecretThings SecretThings = CreateSecretThings(/* snip */);
            return SecretThings.Id;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object  correlationState)
        {
             MyCore.SecretThings req = _My.GetSecretThingsOnThread();
            // if we didn't find the SecretThings, there is nothing to stop() and no data to put in the MessageHeaders
            if (req == null) return;

            MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            reply = buffer.CreateMessage();

            var MyHeader = new MyMessageHeader(/* snip */);
            reply.Headers.Add(MyHeader);
            req.Stop(MyCore.Status.SUCCESS);
        }

        protected MyCore.SecretThings CreateSecretThings(string key, Dictionary<string, string> ids)
        {
            /* snip */
            return _My.GetSecretThings(/* snip */);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see an example? Are your objects that you want to dispose within your DispatchMessageInspector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having a look at the DispatchMessageInspector and how it is implemented.

As you probably know you register your MessageInspectors with an IEndpointBehavior (adding endpoint behaviours through configuration or code). You create an instance of your DispatchMessageInspector within the EndpointBehaviour.

```
   public class MyBehaviour : IEndpointBehavior
{     

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
       System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection
                                            bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        var inspector = new SampleMessageInspector(); //register
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

}
```

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx Endpoint behaviours are registered by the Service Host

> These behavior collections are automatically populated during the ServiceHost and ChannelFactory construction process with any behaviors that are found in your code (via attributes) or within the configuration file (more on this shortly). You can also add behaviors to these collections manually after construction. The following example shows how to add the ConsoleMessageTracing to the host as a service behavior:
>
> ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ZipCodeService));
>   host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ConsoleMessageTracing());

And further dictates that the ServiceHost has a lifetime as long as the service...

> ServiceHost extension objects remain in memory for the lifetime of the ServiceHost while InstanceContext and OperationContext extension objects only remain in memory for the lifetime of the service instance or operation invocation. Your custom dispatcher/proxy extensions can use these collections to store (and look up) user-defined state throughout the pipeline.

I'm assuming this is why your objects within your MessageInspectors are never being destroyed.

Some would see it as an anti-pattern but I would possibly recommend a ServiceLocator that your MessageInspectors can use to retrieve objects. You could then look at setting their lifetime as long as its parent usage?

```
    public class SampleMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{             

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        var objectToDispose = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ObjectToDispose>();

        //do your work
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        //do some other work
    }
}
```

**To follow on from what i've mentioned...**

As an example this post mentions using Ninject as the IoC container and set the life time of your objects as the lifetime of the WCF service

> Bind(...).To(...).InScope(() => OperationContext.Current)

[Ninject WCF Garbage Collection on repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094896/ninject-wcf-garbage-collection-on-repositories#answers-header)

You could then get access to the Ninject Kernal through the ServiceLocator and the objects (_MyProperties etc...) would be disposed off

Comment: I like this answer, @Mike. Very thorough and provides links to additional info on topics mentioned. It will take me a little while to digest this and try to apply to my exact scenario.

Comment: Let me know if you would like more help.